# How to Sync Woocommerce and CRM via External API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multisite

I have one Custom CRM which is having it's own API and i want to sync Woocommerce to that CRM with both ways I mean when i create , edit , update or delete Woocommerce products from Wordpress Website that products should be updated to that CRM as well and if i create new products in that CRM then that products should be added into woocommerce (Wordpress Website) as well

Comment: I guess your options are either to 1) find a way of syncing the databases, including mapping the schemas as part of the synchronisation; 2) use hooks on both systems to call APIs on the other systems to make the same updates there; 3) choose one of the systems as the primary source of data, have that one reflect all changes to the other one and if you make a change to the non-primary system then rather than updating its own database it makes an API call to the other one and has the change reflected back to it.

Comment: But since your CRM is a custom one then I doubt anything would exist already to do this for you, so chances are you'll have to develop this all yourself.

Comment: Hi @test test, did you find any solution for this? I am similar development and I don't know from where to start and didn't find any solution. Can you share your solution in case you find it? many thanks.